# Tax calculator output diplays result in incorrect tax bracket?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, tax

I recently wrote a Python tax calculator for my mother, who is an accountant. It seems to work just fine, but she hates using the terminal, so I decided to re-write it in JavaScript which I am currently learning at university. Here is the Python calculator:

```
print("Welcome to the tax calculator!")

assessible_income = int(input("Enter your assessible income in AUD: "))
allowable_deductions = int(input("Enter your allowable deductions in AUD: "))

taxable_income = assessible_income - allowable_deductions

tax_bracket_0 = range(0, 18201)
tax_bracket_1 = range(18201, 45001)
tax_bracket_2 = range(45001, 120001)
tax_bracket_3 = range(120001, 180001)
tax_bracket_4 = range(180001, 1000000)

if (taxable_income in tax_bracket_0):
    print("You do not pay any tax.")
elif (taxable_income in tax_bracket_1):
    print("You will pay $0 tax on the first $18200 of your income, and 19 cents for each dollar over $18200.")
    tax = ((taxable_income - 18200)*0.19)
    medicare_levy = taxable_income*0.02
    total_tax = tax + medicare_levy
    print("You will pay", total_tax, "dollars in tax, including Medicare levy.")
    print("Your Medicare levy is, in AUD: ", medicare_levy)
elif (taxable_income in tax_bracket_2):
    print("You will pay $5092 plus $0.325 for each $1 over $45000.")
    tax1 = ((5092) + ((taxable_income - 45000)*0.325))
    medicare_levy1 =  taxable_income*0.02
    total_tax1 = tax1 + medicare_levy1
    print("You will pay", total_tax1, "dollars in tax, including Medicare levy.")
    print("Your Medicare levy is, in AUD: ", medicare_levy1)
elif (taxable_income in tax_bracket_3):
    print("You will pay $29467 plus $0.37 for every dollar over 120000")
    tax2 = ((29467) + ((taxable_income - 120000)*0.37))
    medicare_levy2 = taxable_income*0.02
    total_tax2 = tax2 + medicare_levy2
    print("You will pay", total_tax2, "dollars in tax, including Medicare levy.")
    print("Your Medicare levy is, in AUD: ", medicare_levy2)
elif (taxable_income in tax_bracket_4):
    print("You will pay $51667 plus $0.45 for each dollar over $180000.")
    tax3 = ((51667) + ((taxable_income - 180000)*0.45))
    medicare_levy3 = taxable_income*0.02
    total_tax3 = tax3 + medicare_levy3
    print("You will pay", total_tax3, "dollars in tax, including Medicare levy.")
    print("Your Medicare levy is, in AUD: ", medicare_levy3)
else:
    print("You have too much money for this calculator. Good luck.")
```

The JavaScript calculator does not function like the Python one does, though. It appears to work for income values of up to 75000 with 0 deductions, but after that, it appears to calculate to the wrong tax bracket. Running the two scripts side-by-side should highlight the difference. Here is the JS:

```js
function range(start, end) {
  const ans = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    ans.push(i);
  }
  return ans;
}

const taxBracketZero = range(1, 18201);
const taxBracketOne = range(18201, 45001);
const taxBracketTwo = range(45001, 120001);
const taxBracketThree = range(120001, 180001);
const taxBracketFour = range(180001, 1000000)

function calculateTax() {
  let income = document.getElementById("income").value;
  let deductions = document.getElementById("deductions").value;
  let tax = income - deductions

  if (tax in taxBracketZero) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You do not pay any tax.";
  } else if (tax in taxBracketOne) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You will pay $0 tax on the first $18200 of your income, and 19 cents for each dollar over $18200.";
    let taxable_income = ((tax - 18200) * 0.19);
    let medicare_levy = tax * 0.02;
    let total_tax = taxable_income + medicare_levy;
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "You will pay " + total_tax + " dollars in tax, including Medicare levy.";
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "Your Medicare levy is, in AUD: " + medicare_levy;
  } else if (tax in taxBracketTwo) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You will pay $5092 plus $0.325 for each $1 over $45000.";
    let taxable_income = ((5092) + ((tax - 45000) * 0.325));
    let medicare_levy = tax * 0.02;
    let total_tax = taxable_income + medicare_levy;
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "You will pay " + total_tax + " dollars in tax, including Medicare levy."
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "Your Medicare levy is, in AUD: " + medicare_levy;
  } else if (tax in taxBracketThree) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You will pay $29467 plus $0.37 for every dollar over 120000";
    let taxable_income = ((29467) + ((tax - 120000) * 0.37));
    let medicare_levy = tax * 0.02;
    let total_tax = taxable_income + medicare_levy;
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "You will pay ", total_tax, " dollars in tax, including Medicare levy.";
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "Your Medicare levy is, in AUD: " + medicare_levy;
  } else if (tax in taxBracketFour) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You will pay $51667 plus $0.45 for each dollar over $180000.";
    let taxable_income = (51667) + ((tax - 180000) * 0.45);
    let medicare_levy = tax * 0.02;
    let total_tax = taxable_income + medicare_levy;
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "You will pay " + total_tax + " dollars in tax, including Medicare levy.";
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "Your Medicare levy is, in AUD: " + medicare_levy;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have too much money for this calculator. Good luck!"
  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Tax Calculator</h2>

  <h3>Enter your assessible income in AUD:</h3>
  <input type="text" id="income" name="income">
  <h3>Enter your allowable deductions in AUD:</h3>
  <input type="text" id="deductions" name="deductions">
  <button type="button" onclick="calculateTax()">Calculate my tax!</button>
  <p id="result"></p>
  <p id="result1"></p>
  <p id="result2"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

I am very very confused and would really appreciate some help. Thank you!

Comment: Which values give you a wrong result? Any example?

Comment: `if (tax in taxBracketZero)` is not how you check if a value is in an array in JavaScript. You should use `if (taxBracketZero.contains(tax))`

Comment: What you wrote checks if `tax` is an index of the array, not a value in the array.

Comment: @technophyle 80000 gives an incorrect result when compared to the Python script, which gives the correct result.

Comment: @Barmar, would using includes() solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is misunderstanding the `in` operator. As described in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), `in` operator is to check whether an object contains a property or not.

Since arrays are also objects, the code above does not produce a compile error but the meaning of the operator is *not* what you expect. Basically what it means is that *the array contains that property/key*, which is the index in case of an array:

```
if (1 in [1, 2, 3]) {
  console.log('index 1 exists!);
}

if (1 in [4, 5, 6]) {
  // this condition also evaluates to true because the array also has the index range of 0-2, and 1 is among them.
  console.log('index 1 exists here too!);
}
```

In order to evaluate whether the value exists in the array, you need to use `indexOf()` or `includes()`:

```
if ([1, 2, 3].includes(1)) {
  console.log('value 1 exists!');
}

if ([4, 5, 6].indexOf(1) > -1) {
  // this condition doesn't evaluate to true because there's no value 1 in the array
  console.log('value 1 exists here too!');
}
```